# I want to save Multiple checkbox selected options into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

i have searched a lot, but didn't find any solution. i want to save checkbox selected options in SQL. if user selects two check boxes thay must save in MySQL with comma separated.

Kinly please help me in solving this

**HTML CODE**

```
<input name="patno" id="patno">
<input type="checkbox" name="newt[]" value="Diesel" id="type" />Diesel
<input type="checkbox" name="newt[]" value="Petrol" id="type" />Petrol
<input type="checkbox" name="newt[]" value="Electricity" id="type" />Electricity
```

**PHP CODE**

```
$order = "INSERT INTO tblsampo
            (patno, stno, newt)
            VALUES
            ('$smonth',
            '$patno','$stno','$newt')";

$result = mysql_query($order);  //order executes
if($result){
    echo("<br>Input data is succeed");
} else{
    echo("<br>Input data is fail");
}
?>
```

Comment: Side note, IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: @sircapsalot this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341639/how-to-save-checkbox-value-into-mysql-database-using-php and few many. but no use. they are confusing me a lot :(

Comment: Once you get the type array, `implode` it before storing in the database. Also, the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and should not be used and your checkbox elements need to have unique ids if that are going to have ids

Comment: avoid using php closing tags if its the end of file since rendering it might cause some problems if there are some spaces afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply implode the $_POST['type'] array like so....

```
$types = implode(",", $_POST['type']);
```

Then insert that $types variable into your table...

So...

```
$types = implode(",", $_POST['type']);

if($types){
$order = "INSERT INTO tblsampo
        (patno, stno, type)
        VALUES
        ('$smonth',
        '$patno','$stno','$types')";}
```

Comment: ID's of what must be unique??  Each entry?  Simply add a PRIMARY INDEX to your sql table, and auto increment

Comment: Oh yeah, and you should be using PDO instead of the deprecated mysql_* functions

Comment: If you look at the given HTML code, all three checkboxes have `id="type"` ... while this does not affect functionality of the form submission, it is incorrect. I believe that is what j08691 was referring to

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
$newt = false;
if (isset($_POST['newt']) && !empty($_POST['newt']) && is_array($_POST['newt'])){
   $newt = implode(",", $_POST['newt']);
}
```

then just run your query same way but check if **$myTypes** is not **false** first

```
if ($newt) {
  //YOUR QUERY. TIP: use PDO or MySQLi instead of MySQL_* functions
}
```

Comment: thanks for taking time for this question. i had just changed my question and updated name="newt" can you please update your answer with 'newt' please!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$types = implode(',',$_POST['type']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO tblsampo
        (patno, stno, type)
        VALUES
        ('$smonth',
        '$patno','$stno','$types')";
mysql_query($sql)
```